# Creating an interface for react-native dynamic component (wrapper element)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
export interface IWEProps {
  accessibilityLabel: string;
  onPress?: ((status: string | undefined) => void) | undefined;
  localePrefix: string;
  children: JSX.Element[];
  style: IWEStyle;
  type?: string;
}

class WrappingElement extends  React.PureComponent<IWEProps> {
  render() {
    const {
      onPress, children, type, accessibilityLabel, style,
    } = this.props;

    return onPress ? (
      <TouchableOpacity
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        style={style}
        type={type}
        onPress={() => onPress(type)}
      >
        { children }
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : (
      <View
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        style={style}
        type={type}
      >
        { children }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I am doing, and this is an error I'm getting on `type` prop in `View` and `TouchableOpacity`:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is straight forward: The prop `type` does not exist for the components `View` and `TouchableOpacity`. The available [props for View are documented here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view). The available [props for TouchableOpacity are documented here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity).

Since you are not doing anything with `type` in `WrappingElement` other than passing it to `View` and `TouchableOpacity` and the `onPress` function, you can just remove this prop. The following code is equivalent to yours, but does not throw the type error.

```js
export interface IWEProps {
  accessibilityLabel: string;
  onPress?: ((status: string | undefined) => void) | undefined;
  localePrefix: string;
  children: JSX.Element[];
  style: IWEStyle;
  type?: string;
}

class WrappingElement extends  React.PureComponent<IWEProps> {
  render() {
    const {
      onPress, children, type, accessibilityLabel, style,
    } = this.props;

    return onPress ? (
      <TouchableOpacity
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        style={style}
        onPress={() => onPress(type)}
      >
        { children }
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : (
      <View
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        style={style}
      >
        { children }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using a `type` property. Deleting this one from props, unfortunately, is not solving my issue

Comment: No, removing this one from View and TouchableOpacity. You can keep it for WrappingElement and pass it to onPress as before.